# jqGrid sometimes whiteout on refresh in quirks mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jqgrid, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am using jqGrid and I set `datatype: local`.  After the user enters some parameters I force reload using this function.

```
function populateJQGrid(grid, url) {
    grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        datatype : 'json',
        url      : url
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
    }, 500);
}
```

Then in the gridComplete, i change the datatype back to local:

```
        gridComplete: function() {
           $(this).setGridParam({datatype: 'local'});
        }
```

At the bottom of the grid I have a refresh button, which calls populateJQGrid.  This seems to work mostly.  However sometimes (about 50%) when I press refresh, the JQGrid will go completely WHITE. I can't see anything.

I'm working on a large legacy app, so i can't post working code. Also it only runs with Internet Explorer in Compatibility Mode.

I watch the Network in the F12-tool and the server data is returned ok. I added the setTimeout (above) hoping to fix the problem, but it doesn't help. I tried calling clearGridData, also, but it doesn't help.

Have you seen this before?  Any idea what could cause the jqGrid to disappear? Do you know a different way I can try to reload the grid from the server?

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578228/jqgrid-after-click-on-reload-grid-button-all-data-get-disappear i will try that

Comment: ["quirks mode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) means simulation of IE5 and typically means no `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` before `<html>`. It's not supported as all and jqGrid should stop working. Only very old versions of jqGrid allows quirk mode. **Which version of jqGrid you use?** You added IE8 compatibility tag to the question. Do you specified explicitly that Internet Explorer in IE8 Compatibility Mode? Which value of `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` you use? Setting of `datatype: 'local'` inside of `gridComplete` is very bad. One should use `loadonce: true` instead.